# Kernel Update : Kvm disabled by bios

Tags: kernel, bios, kvm-virtualization

I read a text about kernel stable and I updated my kernel to 3.6.1. And I solved problems like WIFI and resolution but I cant solve kvm disabled by BIOS. Before update I didn't see this `KVM : Disabled by bios` Thanks for helps

Comment: anybody ???????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you considered looking into your BIOS settings? There is usually an "Intel VT" or "Virtualization" option that isn't enabled by default, even on many servers.

Comment: Enabling virtualization in the bios got rid of this error message for me.